# ¿Por que un fichero en Ubuntu server 20.04 aparece entre comillas simples?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo un directorio que contiene  un proyecto el cual ejecuta perfectamente cargando el fichero properties que tengo para arrancar la aplicación. El problema es que me descargado una copia a una nueva carpeta descargándolo del repositorio y me da fallo. El tema es que al hacer ls en una carpeta y en la otra obtengo que ese fichero ConfigFile.ini aparece sin comillas (en el directorio donde funciona bien la aplicación) y con comillas donde falla por no cargar ese fichero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué quiere decir esa comilla simple?
¿Qué solución habría?

Comment: Como has hecho la copia?

Comment: Donde funciona vía nano y copiando el contenido. Y el contenido de la otra carpeta, descargando un ar.gz del repo completo y haciendo la descompresión

Comment: La principal duda es por que me aparece asi

Comment: A ver, te explico... el problema no esta en las comillas sino en que tienes un espacio al principio del archivo, fijate en que la primera comilla esta un poco separaca del primer caracter del nombre del archivo. Las comillas simplemente son mostradas, porque el comando `ls` muestra comillas cuando un nombre de archivo tiene un espacio

Comment: Entonces.. entiendo que tu problema reside ahi, tu codigo busca un archivo llamado `ConfigFile.ini` sin espacio y no lo encuentra porque el archivo tiene un espacio al principio

Comment: Yo creo que tu problema esta en la forma en la que has creado el `tar.gz` o sino en la forma en la que lo has descomprimido

Comment: Es como linux delimita el total del nombre de fichero cuando comienza con espacio. Muchas gracias @adrigo

Comment: No tiene que ver con el comienzo, si tienes un espacio entre medias del nombre, tambien salen las comillas

Comment: Si escribes `ls -N` no te escribira las comillas